# SQLite - remove duplicate column in a left outer join

Tags: sql, sqlite

I am doing a `left outer join` over 6 tables, but I dont want the query to keep the duplicated columns. In SQLite the duplicate column are renamed with underscore and added into the view.

Is it possible to remove them in the same query?

```
SELECT * FROM AQ_ADRESSES
LEFT OUTER JOIN AQ_CP_ADRESSES ON AQ_ADRESSES.IdAdr = AQ_CP_ADRESSES.IdAdr
LEFT OUTER JOIN AQ_ODONYMES ON AQ_ADRESSES.Seqodo = AQ_ODONYMES.Seqodo
LEFT OUTER JOIN AQ_REFERENTIEL ON AQ_ADRESSES.NoSqNoCivq = AQ_REFERENTIEL.NoSqNoCivq
LEFT OUTER JOIN AQ_MUNICIPALITES ON AQ_ADRESSES.CodeMun = AQ_MUNICIPALITES.CodeMun
LEFT OUTER JOIN AQ_ARRONDISSEMENTS ON AQ_ADRESSES.CodeArr = AQ_ARRONDISSEMENTS.CodeArr
```

Comment: define "remove". What do you expect to get?

Comment: I dont want the columns that was used to join the tables because by definition the values would be the same

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As your join columns have the same name, you can use the `using` operator to define the join. In that case the "duplicate" columns will not be part of the result set

```
SELECT * 
FROM AQ_ADRESSES
  LEFT OUTER JOIN AQ_CP_ADRESSES using (IdAdr)
  LEFT OUTER JOIN AQ_ODONYMES using (Seqodo)
  LEFT OUTER JOIN AQ_REFERENTIEL  using (NoSqNoCivq)
  LEFT OUTER JOIN AQ_MUNICIPALITES using (CodeMun)
  LEFT OUTER JOIN AQ_ARRONDISSEMENTS using (CodeArr)
```

Tested in SQLite 3.8, don't know if this works the same in earlier versions. But this behavior is required by the SQL standard.

But in general `select *` is considered harmful in code that is used in production.

Comment: Ohh! I didn't know that feature!

Comment: What to do, if I have different columns?
For example: `AQ_ADRESSES.X = AQ_REFERENTIEL.Y`